# In Firefox, getting error in console "XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag" for input

Tags: html, firefox

I am getting the following error when opening up my page in Firefox (other browsers don't show this error). I am using HTML5 and if I try to put closing tags on the input, then the page fails validation.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
    <!--... more here...-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--... more here...-->
    <input type="text" id="wall_color_picker" onclick="startColorPicker(this)" title="Wall Color" value="#FFFFFF">
    <!--... more here...-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit 1: Firefox version is latest (59.0.2 (64-bit))

Edit 2: Response headers:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=604800, public
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 24 Apr 2018 16:04:19 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterpri…penSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.35
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
Transfer-Encoding    chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.6.35
```

Comment: Please share firefox version. Also please add the output of `curl -v <youurpageurl>` to your question

Comment: Can you try `Help->Restart without addons...` and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `<input>`has no content allot of times people do not close the tag `<input></input>` but in your case close it at the end of it like so `<input type="text" id="wall_color_picker" onclick="startColorPicker(this)" title="Wall Color" value="#FFFFFF"/>`

Please try the following,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
    <!--... more here...-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--... more here...-->
    <input type="text" id="wall_color_picker" onclick="startColorPicker(this)" title="Wall Color" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <!--... more here...-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In HTML5, it is valid to have self-closing tags not have the trailing slash that was needed in XHTML/HTML4. Therefore, `<input>` and `<input />` are the same.

Comment: You are correct about HTML5 not having the trailing slash, but nothing worse than having an 80 year old woman calling you because her browser is not up to date. In W3C Recommendation, 14 December 2017 Section 8.1.2.1. for Start tags. if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/). This character has no effect on void elements. If it does not hurt the code why not use it to make it backward compatible as possible.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Your browser is reading your html in an older format

## EDIT:

I'd like you to try two more things

1. > [In Firefox, select View Page Info from the context menu, and look for Render Mode.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)
2. Update to Firefox beta 60 `Help -> About Firefox -> Update`

---

It would seem that your browser is reading your code in the XHTML format which requires strict tags among other things. Ensure that your firefox is up to date, and also replace this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

with this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Reason:

> [This is another element that’s been simplified since XHTML and HTML4, and is an optional feature, but recommended. In the past, you may have written it like this](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Firefox version issue. I have tried that code snippet in Firefox  **43.0.1** and found OK. You can please update the Firefox version.